# Some commands can see a directory but not others?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ls

There's a directory that had gone missing, I never intentionally deleted it (might've been accidental). Assume the directory structure is:

```
/parent
  /dir
    dirFile.js
  parentFile.js
```

If I'm in `/parent`:

```
$ ls
parentFile.js

$ ls -a
.
..
parentFile.js

$ mkdir dir
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘dir’: File exists

$ rm -rf dir
<empty>

$ ls dir
<empty>

$ stat dir
  File: dir
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fh/15d  Inode: 1688849861548050  Links: 0
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/       l)   Gid: ( 1000/       l)
Access: 2020-07-14 16:35:37.808833200 -0400
Modify: 2020-07-14 16:35:37.808833200 -0400
Change: 2020-07-14 16:35:37.808833200 -0400
 Birth: -
```

When this directory was last available, I modified `dir/dirFile.js` and ran `git commit`. Then, I noticed `dir` disappeared, so I ran `git reset HEAD~1 --mixed`. However, the file didn't come back and `git status` shows it was deleted.

I'm unable to `git stash` to undo the delete because it throws `error: unable to create file dir/dirFile.js: No such file or directory`.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 on WSL.

What's going on here?